# Create object of type specified in a string

Tags: c#, class, generics, types

I have a bunch of classes generated by EF that are simple tables and have similar structures:

```
public class Contact
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Member
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I've also got a method for returning an object of a specified type:

```
public T GetInstance<T>(string type)
{
    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(type));
}
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
public ActionResult GetAll(string ClassType)        // ClassType will be the name of one of the classes above
{
    Object LookupType = GetInstance<Object>(ClassType);

    List<LookupType> AllList = new List<LookupType>();

    AllList = repo.GetAll<LookupType>().ToList<LookupType>();    // some generic method that will return a list;
}
```

This makes the compiler mad because I'm using a variable (LookupType) rather than a true type to build the list.  However, neither of these work either:

```
List<LookupType.GetType()> Items = new List<LookupType.GetType()>();
List<typeof(LookupType)> Items = new List<typeof(LookupType)>();
```

Both cause an error - "Using generic type List requires 1 type argument".

Is there a proper way to do this?  Is there a way to convert ClassType directly to a type without first making it an object (from which I hope to derive the type)?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `CreateInstance` method

```
SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject();
Type type = someObject.GetType();

Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new [] { type });
IList list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

Comment: Thanks - IList won't cut it because it can't use it in EF lambda queries.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it with C#!! 
Compiler must to know the parameter type.
In that maybe you would like to accomplish, interfaces will help you

```
public class Contact: IIdDescription
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Member: IIdDescription
{
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }
}

public interface IIdDescription
{
     int ID { get; set; }
     string Description { get; set; }
}



public ActionResult GetAll(string type)         
{
   var AllList = new List<IIdDescription>();

   if(type == Member.GetType().Name)
      AllList = repo.Set<Member>().Cast<IIdDescription >().ToList();
   if(type == Contact.GetType().Name)
       AllList = repo.Set<Contact>().Cast<IIdDescription >().ToList();

   ...
}
```

and into your view use interface as model, something like

```
 @model IEnumerable<IIdDescription>
```

Comment: Having a case statement (or multiple If-thens) is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: into your repo DbContext you should create a Dictionary<string,DBSet<TEntity>> where TEntity:class and use it as 
      AllList = repo.MyDict[type].ToList().Cast<IIdDescription>()

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the type ahead of time maybe using a list of dynamic objects can help.

```
    var item = GetInstance<Contact>("Namespace.Contact");
    var items = new List<dynamic>();

    items.Add(item);
```

You can then access the types like so...

```
Contact contact = items[0];
```

Just be aware that using dynamic can be expensive.